# Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders in react

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, infinite, rerender

This is my code. Home.js
I have used react-redux hooks useSelector and useDispatch to use state and dispatch requests.

```
import React from 'react'
import StyledBanner from '../../components/StyledBanner';
import FeaturedRoom from './FeaturedRoom';
import Hero from '../../components/Hero'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchRooms, fetchFeatured} from '../../redux'


function Home() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    dispatch(fetchRooms())
    dispatch(fetchFeatured())
    const featuredRooms = useSelector(state=>state.roomReducer.featuredRooms)
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid p-0">
            <Hero>
                <StyledBanner title="best rooms" subtitle="subtitle">
                    <div className="subtitle">
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-warning">Rooms</button>
                </StyledBanner>   
            </Hero>
            <FeaturedRoom featuredRooms={featuredRooms}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

This is FeaturedRoom.js

```
import React from 'react'
import StyledTitle from '../../components/StyledTitle';
import StyledButton from '../../components/StyledButton'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export function FeaturedRoom({featuredRooms}) {
    return (
        <div className="mt-3  mb-3 featured-container">
            <div className="featured-wrapper">
                <StyledTitle title="featured rooms"/>
                <div className="featured-rooms">

                    {
                        featuredRooms.map(room=>(
                            <div key={room.id} className="featured-item">
                                <div className="price-tag">
                                    <span>Rs {room.price}</span>
                                    <span>per night</span>
                                </div>
                                <img src={room.images[0]} className="img-fluid" alt="featured-img"/>
                                <Link to="/"><button>Room</button></Link>
                                <div className="room-name">
                                    {room.name}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default FeaturedRoom
```

In second part FeaturedRoom.js file, there is 'Link'. Until I click the button, everything works fine. Reducers are also working fine. All the reducers set state perfectly but, when I click on the button, it says

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14815)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the Home component right after the dispatch assignment.  You are calling dispatch with two actions in the Component definition.  If you would like these actions to be fired upon mount, then put them in a `useEffect` hook.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import StyledBanner from '../../components/StyledBanner';
import FeaturedRoom from './FeaturedRoom';
import Hero from '../../components/Hero'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchRooms, fetchFeatured} from '../../redux'


function Home() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const featuredRooms = useSelector(state=>state.roomReducer.featuredRooms)

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchRooms())
        dispatch(fetchFeatured())
    }, [dispatch])

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid p-0">
            <Hero>
                <StyledBanner title="best rooms" subtitle="subtitle">
                    <div className="subtitle">
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-warning">Rooms</button>
                </StyledBanner>   
            </Hero>
            <FeaturedRoom featuredRooms={featuredRooms}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

In this case, we are using the `useEffect` in a similar fashion to the old `componentDidMount`.  The official docs for that hook are [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

It also occurs to me (given your function names) that you are trying to make a call to a repo to retrieve the featured rooms, load the result into the store, then select it from the store, then feed to `FeaturedRoom` component.  If that's the case, I would recommend wrapping `Home` in a component that makes the call upon mount, and loads the redux store.  A child component could then make use of the `useSelctor` hook, in conjunction with the `useEffect` hook (to watch for changes in the `featuredRooms` part of the store) to feed the results to `FeaturedRoom`.  I hope that's somewhat clear.

## Edit:

Ok, let's try this and see how it works for you.  Move the selector inside the component that needs that data.  Something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import StyledBanner from '../../components/StyledBanner';
import FeaturedRoom from './FeaturedRoom';
import Hero from '../../components/Hero'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchRooms, fetchFeatured} from '../../redux'


function Home() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchRooms())
        dispatch(fetchFeatured())
    }, [dispatch])


    return (
        <div className="container-fluid p-0">
            <Hero>
                <StyledBanner title="best rooms" subtitle="subtitle">
                    <div className="subtitle">
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-warning">Rooms</button>
                </StyledBanner>   
            </Hero>
            <FeaturedRoom />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home


function FeaturedRoom() {
    const featuredRooms = useSelector(state=>state.roomReducer.featuredRooms);

    /*  .... the rest of your component ... */
}
```

If you need to watch for changes on the `featuredRooms` property, you can place that logic in another `useEffect` within the `FeaturedRoom` component.

Comment: Thank You. It worked. I wrapped the home component and so on...

Comment: When I used useEffet that you suggested above, it was throwing following error. Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
Eventually, I wrapped components as follow in index.js and worked `ReactDOM.render(
`  <Provider store={store}>
      <RoomProvider>
        <Router>
          <App />
        </Router>
      </RoomProvider>
    </Provider>
  document.getElementById('root')
);` where RoomProvider loads the store.